# Converting PDF export into xlsm within looprange

Tags: excel, vba, loops, save, xlsm

I have an interesting issue where I am trying to have a looprange in effect and before looping to the next data point it will save a copy of the worksheet. Does anyone have any experience, when I try to make the changes it causes issues with my Next statement at the bottom of the code.

'''
Sub Excel1()

Dim rngLoopRange As Range
   Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
   Dim rngDealers As Worksheet

Set wsSummary = Sheets("PL")

For Each rngLoopRange In Worksheets("AUX").Range("A1:A38")
      wsSummary.Range("C12").Value = rngLoopRange.Value

```
Application.Run "TM1REFRESH"

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("C12")
ws.Copy before = wb.Worksheets(1)
```

Next rngLoopRange

Set wsSummary = Nothing

```
MsgBox "Complete!", vbInformation
```

End Sub
'''

Comment: "Issues"? Do you get an error message? What is it? Could you include the beginning of the loop as well? You may also want to include the exact values of your variables/range when it errors.

Comment: I'm really just trying to get a replacement code for the pdf export and replace it with a save worksheet as new workbook without causing issues with the Next code.

Comment: Well then you should probably explain what the issues are...

Comment: Just getting a 'Next without For' error when I replace it with some save code

Comment: Yes, well that is kinda my point... you dont have a matching `For` statement in your question, so if that's all the code you are using, it's not going to work.

Comment: ''''
 Sub Excel1()

   Dim rngLoopRange As Range
   Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
   Dim rngDealers As Worksheet
   
   Set wsSummary = Sheets("PL")

   For Each rngLoopRange In Worksheets("AUX").Range("A1:A38")
      wsSummary.Range("C12").Value = rngLoopRange.Value
      
    Application.Run "TM1REFRESH"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    wb.SaveAs Range("I11")
       
   Next rngLoopRange
   
   Set wsSummary = Nothing
   
    MsgBox "Complete!", vbInformation
    
End Sub
'''

Comment: Sorry, attached is the full code that won't format properly, I'm attempting to run through the loop and at each instance of the loop it saves a new workbook with the information on.

Comment: Please post your code in your question by editing it.